# Perl: Forking and Populating Parent Array

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

***Disclaimer:** With today's hardware being what it is, I haven't had to fork in a while and so I may need some advice on the following code.  The following is also a simple example, not actual code.*

```
my @matched;
my @names = qw/jim john sally/;

foreach my $name (@names) {
   my $pid;
   next if $pid = fork;                                # child birth
   croak "Fork failed: $!" if not defined $pid;        # terminate if child wasn't born

   my $result = `command_to_get_some_list_of_names`;   # sam sue john tyler
   my @list   = split /\s/, $result;

   foreach my $match ( @list ){
      push(@matched,$match) if $name eq $match;        # where want to access parent array
   }

   exit;                                               # child funeral
}

1 while (wait() != -1);                                # wait for children to finish playing

say "Matched: @matched";                               # nothing; not desired, but expected
```

There are matches made and `@matched` is being populated in the child, but from what I remember, `fork` creates a copy of the parent and what I don't know (and am unsure if I ever did) is how to access the parent's resources.  I would think the simpler way would be to create a temp file on the filesystem, but I'd like to avoid anything external.

Is there an alternative to `fork` that provides a native avenue for threading?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.34/lib/forks/shared.pm it should do sharing like for real threads.

Comment: @mpapec: you beat me to it -- I was just about to say update, what I'm mostly looking for is a thread.  Do you know of something that doesn't involve a module?

Comment: I've had good experience with `threads::shared` and `Thread::Queue`

Comment: @mpapec it looks like my installation wasn't set up to support `threads` and I don't want to have to recompile the binaries.  Any other ideas?

Comment: unfortunately no, but I prefer module over external sharing. sorry to hear that. btw, how about system independent perl? http://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: If your Perl is not compiled to support threads, then you'll have to obtain one that is to be able to use threading -- either downloaded from somewhere or build your own.

Comment: You can use pipes to communicate with the child process. See http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/pod/perlipc.pod#Safe_Pipe_Opens for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) with the [`share`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper#share) option makes this pretty easy:

```
use Carp;
use 5.012;
use Forks::Super;
my @matched;
my @names = qw/jim john sally/;

foreach my $name (@names) {
   my $pid = fork {
     share => [ \@matched ],
     sub => sub {
       #croak "Fork failed: $!" if not defined $pid;

       my $result = "sam sue john tyler";             # sam sue john tyler
       my @list   = split /\s/, $result;

       foreach my $match ( @list ){
           push(@matched,$match) if $name eq $match;  # where want to access parent array
       }
     }
   };
}

waitall;                                              # wait for children to finish playing

say "Matched: @matched";                              # nothing; not desired,
```

Result:

```
Matched: john
```

Comment: I had looked at Forks modules and was kind of hoping for a solution that would be part of Perl and avoid using external modules.  Also, I didn't think this was so, but just wanted to make sure this doesn't require Perl to be threaded.